# How to add Spree email attachment (image) from products.images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, html-email, spree

### I want to attach images to email from products [Spreecommerce](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/views/spree/order_mailer/confirm_email.text.erb). But following code doestn't work.

../app/views/order_mailer/confirm_email.html.erb

```
<% for item in @order.line_items %>

# I'm not sure this product.image containts images. And it doesn't work =(
<%= image_tag image.attachment.url(:product), :itemprop => "image" %>

<%=item.variant.sku %> <%=item.variant.product.name%>
<%= variant_options(item.variant) %>(<%=item.quantity%>) @ <%= number_to_currency item.price %>
<%= number_to_currency(item.price * item.quantity) %>
<% end %>
<%= number_to_currency @order.total %>
```

**More understandable on the following [picture](http://ib3.keep4u.ru/b/2012/05/29/7f/7ff731b88c4f31b58401bf366cfdafd7.jpg).**

Can you ask a solution to add image.products  to confirmation email?

Comment: http://ib3.keep4u.ru/b/2012/05/29/7f/7ff731b88c4f31b58401bf366cfdafd7.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

./app/views/order_mailer/confirm_email.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag('http://mysite.com' + item.variant.images.first.attachment.url(:small)), item.variant.product %>
```

Add this line in item block and you'll get image in confirmation email.

Comment: #{root_url} doesn't work without config host file. Thus i used absolute way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like:

```
<%= image_tag "#{root_url}#{image.attachment.url(:product)}", :itemprop => "image" %>
```

You're getting a relative image path, not an absolute url.