# Spree deface email text template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I am trying to insert a text after checkout email message. I'm found template in spree/order_mailer/confirm_email.text.erb

```
<%= Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.dear_customer') %>

<%= Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.instructions') %>

============================================================
<%= Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.order_summary') %>
============================================================
<% @order.line_items.each do |item| %>
<%= item.variant.sku %> <%= raw(item.variant.product.name) %> <%= raw(item.variant.options_text) -%> (<%=item.quantity%>) @ <%= item.single_money %> = <%= item.display_amount %>
<% end %>
============================================================
<%= Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.subtotal', :subtotal => @order.display_item_total) %>

<% @order.adjustments.eligible.each do |adjustment| %>
  <%= raw(adjustment.label) %> <%= adjustment.display_amount %>
<% end %>

<%= Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.total', :total => @order.display_total) %>

<%= Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.thanks') %>
```

So I don't know how to add some text after this, there are no any selectors:

```
Deface::Override.new(
    :virtual_path => "spree/order_mailer/confirm_email",
    :insert_bottom => '*',
    :partial      => "spree/shared/confirm_email",    
    :name         => "confirm_email",
    :original     => '3a8c298b4d9884a4d9f842b23fcb4fabf92ef0f3'
)
```

Could you advice me any ways to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution here: [How to add Spree email attachment (image) from products.images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790106/how-to-add-spree-email-attachment-image-from-products-images). I'm created a new template `/app/views/spree/order_mailer/confirm_email.text.erb` and added my code here.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

Long Answer: Unfortunately you cannot deface a text file as I tried recently. Reason is *Deface needs structured data to parse the view*, as detailed in the [Spree Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/spree-user/Uuf5tB4jfnc/discussion).
Only .deface, .html.erb.deface, .html.haml.deface or .html.slim.deface are the only override files allowed:

```
Deface::DSL does not know how to read '/spree/app/overrides/spree/order_mailer/confirm_email.text/append_text.text.erb.deface'. 
Override files should end with just .deface, .html.erb.deface, .html.haml.deface or .html.slim.deface
```

Interestingly deface is actually able to test the selector on the file but still cannot override:

```
$ bundle exec rake deface:test_selector['spree/order_mailer/confirm_email.text',"erb:contains('order_mailer.confirm_email.thanks')"]

Querying 'spree/order_mailer/confirm_email.text' for 'erb:contains('order_mailer.confirm_email.thanks')'
---------------- Match 1 ----------------
<%= Spree.t('order_mailer.confirm_email.thanks') %>
```

The only thing you can do then is to override the file by creating `app/views/spree/order_mailer/confirm_email.text.erb`